# Figuring out which month the user is in while using v-calender

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vcalendar

I have been using v-calendar plugin for one of my web pages. I am stuck in a place where I need to know which month and year the user is looking at to make some specific changes. How can I get this data as the user navigates through the calender.

[image: This is how the calender looks]

Refer to: https://vcalendar.io/ for further details.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/125

This Link helped me to understand and use the @update:page and @update:fromPage attributes of v-calender.This returns a list of of the month and year as the user scrolls through the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the VDatePicker you will see the month is being hold in span with a class of 'v-title'. Follow below steps to get it right

- Add event listner to your VDatePicket element `<VDatePicker      @click="handleMonthChange" />`
- Then bind the funtion

  setTimeout(() => {

  let month = document.getElementsByClassName('vc-title')[0].innerHTML

  console.log( month.split(' ')[0].replace('','') )
  }, 500);

Remember SetTimeout function is important because we need a break between assigning it

Answer (score -1):

Use v-date-picker with mode='range' to get the selected date by user. This wrapper comes with v-calendar. Use the users selected date using v-model to work for specific changes as date changes.

```
<v-date-picker
  mode='range'
  v-model='range'
/>
```

Comment: Can the month be returned to me automatically without the user selecting a date? All I want is when the user, for eg. shifts from May to April in the calendar, my webpage should be able to notice the change and do some tasks